# jdbc driver does not work in java

Tags: java, jdbc

In java, I use jdbc connect to sqlite. the following sentence works,

```
     Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C://Users//13149//Desktop//SqliteDB0.sqlite");
```

When I replace this with the following one.

```
     Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://localhost:3306//Database//SqliteDB0.sqlite")
```

The first time, it does not give any error message, only stop there. However, as I run it again, it always gives error message. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: post your stack trace plz

Comment: The error is probably related to the double slashes you used. Try `jdbc:sqlite://localhost:3306/Database/SqliteDB0.sqlite` instead.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula - The first connection URL supposedly worked, so the double slashes are apparently not the problem *per se*. However, standard SQLite is *not* a client/server database, so `localhost:3306` is never going to work. (BTW, 3306 is the standard port for MySQL.)

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for information similar to the related question [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21/is-it-possible-to-use-sqlite-as-a-client-server-database) on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You should look at this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have gotten the wrong idea. A SQLite database is simply a file...so, the first setup you provided works fine.

The setup you provided would have worked fine on MySQL, for example, since there's a database server running on 3306 port. Since SQLite isn't a client/server database, but a local file, the only viable option is pointing to its physical file.

In case this second setup is supposed to be running on your application server, you just have to create the SQLite physical file and point the connection URL to it, just like you did in first place.

If you really need, for example, to have the database running on another server (different from your application server) you should consider migrating to MySQL/PostgreSQL. Both of them will allow you client/server connection.

Comment: You may be interested in the related question [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21/is-it-possible-to-use-sqlite-as-a-client-server-database) on dba.stackexchange.com.